# How to restore the default repositories to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, pop-os

I have POP!_OS Software and want the original Ubuntu repositories back.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/ 
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then I open Software & Updates and change the server to main and change the sources to the latest Ubuntu release previously installed on my PC and revert it.

Doesn't work. No error it just keeps being POP!_OS installed.

I want to remove pop software. `sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop` gives: `Warning: Could not find package list for PPA: system76 pop`. But it is installed

Help!

Comment: Welcome, you say *"I have POP!_OS Software "*, and *"No error it just keeps being POP!_OS installed."*, what do you mean by that? POP is an OS, as is Ubuntu. You have one installed or the other. Furthermore, POP is based on Ubuntu, so it uses the same repositories.

Comment: https://ibb.co/XLSdPNy and https://ibb.co/8xfdn5h

Comment: Can't post more than 8 links, so here is an edit img https://ibb.co/YQpdhK7

Comment: This is also confusing: Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-7634-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,5 GiB of RAM

Comment: So POP!_OS with KDE Plasma enviroment is still Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) and [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) are different operating systems, even though the former is based on the latter. If you want to switch from Pop!_OS to Ubuntu, you should install Ubuntu; attempting to convert an existing Pop!_OS installation to Ubuntu will only result in frustration.